# Android: How do I implement a service in the foreground or background depending on a condition?

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an app that is going to require 2 services:

1. **`HostService`** - A foreground service that manages music playback using the Spotify app-remote SDK. It is necessary to run this service in the foreground as I need to detect playState changes and manage playback constantly. However, this service ONLY needs to run if a condition is met, we'll call that condition `isHost`. This service will be bound to a `SessionActivity` that displays the music playing and manages playback.
2. **`ApiService`** - A service that continuously polls a separate web API for updates. This must also run in the foreground if the `isHost` condition is met as the updates may influence the music playback. However, if the user is not a host, this can be a background process that only needs to poll while the user is actively using a particular Activity. I'm not sure if this service should also be bound to the activity or not.

My question is, how should I go about setting up the `ApiService` differently depending on this condition? I've started to implement these services below but I'm not entirely sure what I have done makes sense. Additionally, am I doing the right thing by using an event handler the way I am? I don't fully understand Intents and I'm not sure if I should be using broadcast messages and such instead.

#### SessionActivity.java

```java
class SessionActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements HostEventHandler, ApiEventHandler {
    private boolean isHost;
    private String data;
    private String UID;

    private ApiService api;
    private HostService host;

    private boolean hostBound;
    private boolean apiBound;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_session);
        isHost = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("isHost", false);
        data = getIntent().getStringExtra("data");

        UID = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    }

    private ServiceConnection hostConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {

            Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Bound to HostService");
            HostService.LocalBinder binder = (HostService.LocalBinder) service;
            host = (HostService) binder.getService()
            host.registerEventHandler(this);
            hostBound = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
            Log.e(Constants.TAG, "onServiceDisconnected");
            hostService = null;
        }
    };

    private ServiceConnection apiConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {

            Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Bound to ApiService");
            HostService.LocalBinder binder = (ApiService.LocalBinder) service;
            api = (ApiService) binder.getService()
            api.registerEventHandler(this);
            apiBound = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
            Log.e(Constants.TAG, "onServiceDisconnected");
            apiService = null;
        }
    };

    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Binding to services...");

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ApiService.class);
        intent.putExtra("data", data);
        intent.putExtra("user", Constants.UID);
        bindService(intent, connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

        if (isHost) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, HostService.class);
            bindService(intent, connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        unbindService(apiConnection);
        apiBound = false;

        if (isHost) {
            unbindService(hostService);
            hostBound = false;
        }
    }

    // HostEventHandler and ApiEventHandler methods...
}
```

#### HostService.java

```java
public class HostService extends Service {
    private final IBinder binder = new LocalBinder();
    private HostEventHandler handler;

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        HostService getService() {
            return HostService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(Constants.TAG, "onBind");
        return binder;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        createNotificationChannel();
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, SessionActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("Foreground Service")
                .setContentText("Foreground service is running...")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .build();
        startForeground(1, notification);

        connect(); // This connects to spotify

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        disconnect();
    }

    public registerEventHandler(HostEventHandler handler) {
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    private void createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel serviceChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                    CHANNEL_ID,
                    "Foreground Service Channel",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            );
            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel);
        }
    }
}
```

#### ApiService.java

```java
public class ApiService extends Service {
    private final IBinder binder = new LocalBinder();
    private ApiEventHandler handler;
    private final Timer timer;
    private boolean connected = false;

    private String data;
    private String UID;
    private ApiState state;

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        HostService getService() {
            return ApiService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(Constants.TAG, "onBind");
        return binder;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (!connected) {
            data = intent.getStringExtra("data");
            UID = intent.getStringExtra("user");
            connect();
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        disconnect();
    }

    public void registerEventHandler(ApiEventHandler handler) {
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    public ApiState getState() {
        return state;
    }

    private void connect() {
        if (connected) return;
        class Updater extends TimerTask {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                state = fetchUpdatedState(); // This will implement the web request
                handler.onStateUpdate(state);
                Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Polling API...");
                timer.schedule(new Updater(), Constants.REFRESH_DELAY);
            }
        }
        timer.schedule(new Updater(), Constants.REFRESH_DELAY);
        connected = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: "I'm developing an app that is going to require 2 services" -- why do you believe that they need to be services? And, why do you believe that you need two of them? For example, suppose that you do indeed need some of this functionality to be running while your app's UI is not in the foreground, and it needs to be going continuously. That's a justifiable reason for a foreground service... but you only need one. The actual business logic (talking to Spotify, talking to your Web service) is handled by other objects. The service simply arranges for those objects to do their work.

Comment: @CommonsWare Without going into too much detail, my app is monitoring the API to determine what music to play and I am 100% certain I need and want to use a foreground service for this. I suppose they don't necessarily need to be separate services, but that seemed the most logical way to split up the two tasks. If the user is not a host then I don't need to use a service for the web API but figured that was better than clogging up the UI thread with web requests.

Comment: "I suppose they don't necessarily need to be separate services, but that seemed the most logical way to split up the two tasks" -- think of a service as purely a container for processing, much as we consider an activity to be a container of UI. Just as modern Android tends to have a slim activity with the rest of the logic managed by fragments, a service can be a slim container with the logic handled by other objects. That allows those objects to also be used in places where a service is not needed.